# How to update state in Arr object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, state

Hello i have problem with update state in React.

```
const [test, setTest] = useState(
    [
        {
            name: "example1" //i want update single el
        },
        {
            name: "example2" //i want update single el
        }
    ]
)

const updateTest = () => {
    setTest([{ ...test[0], name: "example1 changed"}])
}
```

i want update element without remove another element. For the moment when i click updateTest it cause that my test[1] is removed. Why??

Comment: See [React: Updating state when state is an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662708/react-updating-state-when-state-is-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this:

```
const updateTest = () => {
  const newArray = [...test]; // use proper name
  newArray[0].name = "new-example1";
  setTest(newArray);
}
```

Anyway, generally you want to `map`, `filter` or whatever before updating the state, you should figure it out depending your use case. This one is kind of a test hack

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the element in array and then spread it as a new array or use map in order to overwrite changes with a function.

```
const [test, setTest] = useState(
    [
    {
        name: "example1" //i want update single el
    },
    {
        name: "example2" //i want update single el
    }
    ]
)

const updateTestSplice = () => {
    let temp = ([...test])
    temp.splice(0, { name: "example1 changed" })
    setTest([...temp])
}

const updateTestMap = () => {
    setTest(
        test.map(el =>
            el.name === "example1"
                ? { name: "example1 changed" }
                : el)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did was you set `test` to a new array with only one element. If you just want to add a new element to the array, you can do this:

```
setTest([{ ...test[0], name: "example1 changed"}, ...test]);
```

and you will end up with an array with both the original elements and the added one.

If, on the other hand, you want to replace an element, you can use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
setTest(test.splice(0,1,{ ...test[0], name: "example1 changed"}));
```

where the first argument(0 in this example) is where you want to start (so in this case at the beginning of the array), next argument (1) is how many existing elements you want to remove, and the last one is the element(s) you want to add to that place in the array.