# Form data binding with repeated forms in React

Tags: reactjs, data-binding, next.js

**Parent Component**

I have a parent component `Users` with the following snippet:

```
addUser(index, user) {
    var users = this.state.users
    var existingUser = users[index]
    if (existingUser !== undefined) {
        this.updateUser(index, user)
    } else {
        users.push(user)
        this.setState({
            users : users
        })
    }
}

updateUser(index, itemAttributes) {
    this.setState({
        travellers: [
            ...this.state.users.slice(0,index),
            Object.assign({}, this.state.users[index], itemAttributes),
            ...this.state.users.slice(index+1)
        ]
    });
}
```

The updateUser functionality has been taken from [React: Updating state when state is an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662708/react-updating-state-when-state-is-an-array-of-objects#answer-37663294)

And in JSX I have the following snippet:

```
...
<Form onSubmit={this._handleFormSubmit.bind(this)}>
  <UserDetails index={0} callback = {this.addUser.bind(this)}/>
  <UserDetails index={1} callback = {this.addUser.bind(this)}/>
  <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mb-4" value="Continue"/>
</Form>
...
```

**Child Component**

Then in the child component `UserDetails` I have:

```
handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let formValues = this.state.formValues;
    let name = event.target.name;
    let value = event.target.value;

    formValues[name] = value;

    this.setState({formValues})
    this.props.callback(this.props.index, this.state.formValues)
}
```

And in JSX:

```
<div className="row">
    <div className="col-md-4">
        <FormGroup>
            <Label>First Name</Label>
            <Input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" value={this.state.formValues["firstName"]} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        </FormGroup>
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-4">
        <FormGroup>
            <Label>Last Name</Label>
            <Input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" value={this.state.formValues["lastName"]} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        </FormGroup>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I can see two forms,  each with a `First Name` and a `Last Name` fields. Now the problem is when I enter the `First Name` for the first user, the `First Name` for the second user is also automatically set to that of the first user. Thus, I cannot enter separate names for the two users. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I see that you are mutating the state directly by using `let formValues = this.state.formValues;` and `formValues[name] = value;` 
One way to alleviate this issue is to spread the formValues before assigning `let formValues = {...this.state.formValues};` or you can use [Immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer).

Comment: Thank you @dOshu. Using the spread operator solved my problem. If you would add your comment as an answer, I would accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are mutating the state directly by using

```
let formValues = this.state.formValues; 
formValues[name] = value;
```

One way to alleviate this issue is to spread the formValues before assigning

```
let formValues = {...this.state.formValues};
```

or you can use [Immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer)