# React: Inputs render the same value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple list where in each element there is an input to choose an image to upload.
The choosen image is displaying correctly, but I can't manage to choose different images for different elements.

**My list seems to render the same value for all items.**
**My issue is that any image will be present in all elements. I want a different image for each element.**

This is what I tried so far :

```
  const handleChange = (index, newimage) => {
    const cloneList = [...list];
    cloneList[index].image = newimage;
    setList(cloneList);
  };
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-sid-74le8?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

export default () => {
  const initialList = [
    {
      id: "1",
      image: "https://picsum.photos/150/150.jpg"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      image: " "
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      image: " "
    }
  ];

  const [list, setList] = React.useState(initialList);
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

  const handleFile = (event) => {
    setFile(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
  };

  /* What I tried to change a specific element

  const handleChange = (index, newimage) => {
    const cloneList = [...list];
    cloneList[index].image = newimage;
    setList(cloneList);
  };*/

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <div>
          {list.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <span>
                <input type="file" onChange={handleFile} />
                <img
                  src={file}
                  alt=""
                  style={{ width: "100px", height: "100px" }}
                />
              </span>
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: So something like `setList` to `file` ? Sorry i'm still new to react.

Comment: You are mutating state when you set the `image` property on the cloned list because nested objects are not cloned. See this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662708/react-updating-state-when-state-is-an-array-of-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662708/react-updating-state-when-state-is-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: @pilchard I will be checking it, thank you.