# How can i see my array on my component ? / React / Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-native

I have a element like :

```
const DropdownElements = [
  {
    key: 1,
    title: "Şehir",
    placeholder: "Şehir Seçiniz",
    apiUrl: "https://api.npoint.io/995de746afde6410e3bd",
    type: "city",
    selecteditem: "",
    data : [],
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    title: "İlçe",
    placeholder: "İlçe Seçiniz",
    apiUrl: "https://api.npoint.io/fc801dbd3fc23c2c1679", // its my apis. They hold datas from json
    type: "district",
    selecteditem: "",
    data : [],
  },
]
```

I fetching that url in App in useEffect.

```
const App = () => {
     useEffect(() => {
    DropdownElements.map((x) => {
     
      fetch(x.apiUrl)
        .then((z) => z.json())
        .then((vb) => {
         x.data=vb  // If i write x.data.push(vb) i can see it on my component but its not giving pure array.
         console.log(x.data) // I can see my datas perfectly. I trying fill my data.

          
            
         
        });
      
    });
    
  }, []);
```

And i setting it like that :

```
 <Space>
      {DropdownElements.map((x) => {
        return (
        
          <PickerCompanent
            showSearch
            selecteditem={idhold}
            key={x.key}
            
            placeholder={x.placeholder}
            type={x.type}
            datasource={x.data}  // I gave my datasource x.data that i filled .
            onFocus={onFocus}
            onChange={z=>onChange(z)}
            onFocus={onFocus}
            onSearch={onSearch}
          ></PickerCompanent>
        );
      })}
    </Space>
```

But in my component when i try write like `console.log(props)` my datasource is empty array. How can i see my datas on my component ? I need set my array to a state in my component.

Comment: what is `x` here?

Comment: @ShivamJha `{DropdownElements.map((x) => {`  Its map element for map my element

Comment: **Edit**: ohh. ok. You should out your `DropdownElements` in a state (using [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) hook), then look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662708/react-updating-state-when-state-is-an-array-of-objects) to how to change state with array of object if you are having any doubts

Comment: You can wrap your pickers in a loader component: https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-meadow-ebgov?file=/src/App.js The main problem with your code is that you're changing the state directly (`x.data=vb`) which means React doesn't notice the change and will not re-render.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you aren't using any kind of state in your code.

```
const App = () => {


 const [myData, setMyData] = useState();

     useEffect(() => {
         DropdownElements.map((x) => {
     
              fetch(x.apiUrl)
        .then((z) => z.json())
        .then((vb) => {
         x.data=vb  // If i write x.data.push(vb) i can see it on my component but its not giving pure array.
         console.log(x.data) // I can see my datas perfectly. I trying fill my data.
         // in here you'll want to be adding your data to some state
       // e.g. 
       setMyData(x.data); 

          
            
         
        });
      
    });
    
  }, []);
```

Then within your component, use that state:

```
datasource={myData}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object is updating but not view. To achieve this you need have a component state, to which we can update and trigger return again to update view.

```js
const App = () => {
 const [myData, setMyData] = useState(DropdownElements);

     useEffect(() => {
         myData.map((x, i) => {
             fetch(x.apiUrl)
             .then((z) => z.json())
             .then((result) => {
                myData[i].data = result;
                setMyData(myData);
              });
           });
      }, []);
      
   return (
      <Space>
        {myData.map((x) => {
          return (
            <PickerCompanent
              showSearch
              selecteditem={idhold}
              key={x.key}

              placeholder={x.placeholder}
              type={x.type}
              datasource={x.data}  // I gave my datasource x.data that i filled .
              onFocus={onFocus}
              onChange={z=>onChange(z)}
              onFocus={onFocus}
              onSearch={onSearch}
            ></PickerCompanent>
          );
        })}
      </Space>
   );
```