# Simple counter isn't working with React context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm learning the React contexts and I tried to create a simple counter by using contexts to visualize the concept. Unfortunately, it doesn't work perfectly. The context works fine, but it doesn't work with simple arithmetic. What I mean by it's not working is that value doesn't show up after the incrementation.

**I'm trying to reach the solution without using functional components.**

The whole code is attached here and it's simple.

**CounterContext.js**

```
    import React, {Component, createContext} from "react"

export const CounterContext = createContext()

class CounterContextProvider extends Component {

    state = {
        ourNumber: 0
    }

    addOne = ()=> {
        console.log("addOne is reached")
        this.state.ourNumber = this.state.ourNumber + 1
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <CounterContext.Provider value={{...this.state, addOne: this.addOne}}>
                {this.props.children}
            </CounterContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default CounterContextProvider;
```

**App.js**

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import CounterContextProvider from "./CounterContext";
import CounterPage from "./CounterPage";

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <CounterContextProvider>
              <CounterPage/>
            </CounterContextProvider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**CounterPage.js**

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {CounterContext} from "./CounterContext";

class CounterPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <CounterContext.Consumer>
                {counterContext=>{
                    const {ourNumber, addOne} =counterContext

                    return(
                        <>
                            <h1> { ourNumber } </h1>
                            <p> { ourNumber } </p>
                            <button onClick={()=>{addOne()}}>+1</button>
                        </>
                    )
                }}
            </CounterContext.Consumer>
        );
    }
}

export default CounterPage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the state in class component you should use `setState()` like so:

```js
addOne = () => {
    console.log("addOne is reached")
    this.setState({ourNumber: this.state.ourNumber + 1})
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: seems to work fine, but it shows a red-underline under `ourNumber` right hand side

Comment: which says what ?

Comment: Thank you it worked well. I'm also implementing a shopping cart with the same concept. Is it ok if I got back to you if I had any questions? It will be in the comments here

Comment: If it's something simple it will be ok here I guess.
by the way, can you also mark my answer as resolved?

Comment: I will mark it. It says `You can accept questions in 1 minute`

Comment: Well, my problem was because I didn't use `setState()` but at this time the syntax might be a little bit complex. I have ` state = { productsToPurchase: [] }` . `productsToPurchase` is an array of objects and the object will look like this `{itemId: 'ps-5', qty: 4}`. My problem is with incrementing `qty` to one by using `setState()`. How can I do it? Let me know if something isn't clear.

Comment: It's quite complicated to answer here, but basically you need to get a copy of the array `this.state.slice()` then use `find()` on that variable to find the one you want to increment, then  increment `qty` and then `setState()` the array that copied.
This can help you understand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662708/react-updating-state-when-state-is-an-array-of-objects

Comment: I just posted my question. Could you please check it? That didn't answer my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69968017/updating-state-when-state-is-an-array-of-objects-react