# Updating state when state is an array of objects. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm working on a shopping cart in react by using context. My problem is with changing the state that has an array of objects.

My array will look like this `[{itemId: 'ps-5', qty:4}, {itemId: 'iphone-xr', qty:2}]`

Here is my code check the comment

```
export const CartContext = createContext()

class CartContextProvider extends Component {

    state = {
        productsToPurchase: []
    }

    addProduct = (itemId)=> {
        if (JSON.stringify(this.state.productsToPurchase).includes(itemId)){
            // Add one to the qty of the product
            this.state.productsToPurchase.map(product=>{
                if (product.itemId === itemId){
                    // This is wrong I have to use setState(), but the syntax is a little bit complex
                    product.qty = product.qty + 1
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            this.state.productsToPurchase.push({itemId: itemId, qty: 1})
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <CartContext.Provider value={{...this.state, addProduct: this.addProduct}}>
                {this.props.children}
            </CartContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default CartContextProvider;
```

Comment: Did you have a specific question or error condition to share or code sample that you tried to get to work but can't, or are you just looking for someone to code this up for you?

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing here?

Comment: @decpk I'm trying to use `useState()` in order to change the some value in an array of objects.

Comment: My array will look like this `[{itemId: 'ps-5', qty:4}, {itemId: 'iphone-xr', qty:2}]` I will edit my question to mention that for everyone.

Comment: @asemshaat You have a class component and `useState` is a hook and hooks don't work in class component

Comment: @RandyCasburn I have an a bug and the reason why I have it is because I don't use `setState()` function. I just don't know how to use `useState()` in my case as it is going to be complicated

Comment: What @decpk said.

Comment: You can't use `useState` in a class-based component. There's no real difference in how to handle arrays either way. The issue is that you're modifying state directly.

Comment: @decpk I tried `useState()` in a class component before and it works fine.

Comment: @asemshaat can't be possible, `Hooks` doesn't work in class componenet. This is one of two condition to work with react hooks. please go throught this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions)

Comment: @DaveNewton  I tried useState() in a class component before and it works fine.

Comment: @decpk I had a simple question before about this and it works fine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69967731/simple-counter-isnt-working-with-react-context/69967757?noredirect=1#comment123683031_69967757

Comment: @decpk Sorry that was `setState()`

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry I meant `setState()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the state directly, but you have to use `this.setState` to update it,

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
addProduct = (itemId) => {
  this.setState((oldState) => {
    const objWithIdExist = oldState.productsToPurchase.find((o) => o.itemId === itemId);
    return {
      productsToPurchase: !objWithIdExist
        ? [...oldState.productsToPurchase, { itemId, qty: 1 }]
        : oldState.productsToPurchase.map((o) =>
            o.itemId !== itemId ? o : { ...o, qty: o.qty + 1 }
          )
    };
  });
};
```

Comment: That works well. But I didn't understand the syntax for what comes after the return

Comment: What I didn't get exactly is this `[...oldState.productsToPurchase, { itemId, qty: 1 }]` and `o.itemId !== itemId ? o : { ...o, qty: o.qty + 1 }`

Comment: You should read [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [Ternary conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)